# Buttons in SWF file quickly make two click, With Eclipse ADT

Tags: eclipse, flash, actionscript, air

Beginning, excuse my English.

I made an application with Eclipse (ADT) to run a SWF file, it worked without problems in older tablet, but to run this application on tablet like Samsung or Phillips, buttons swf file takes two click quickly.

If I compile the FLA with Actionscript 3 and AIR 3.2 APK generating a file, SWF buttons work well.

How could "slow down" the multitouch of the new tablet? imagine this causes the error, because by AIR, the SWF file is ok, then the problem is not new but tablet code.

My code is:

```
        public class modulo1 extends Activity {
        WebView mWebView;

        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        @Override  
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {       
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.modulo1);

            mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);     
            mWebView.clearCache(true);
            mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            mWebView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(false);
            mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
            mWebView.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(false);    
            mWebView.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);
            mWebView.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);
            mWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_res/raw/modulo1.swf");             
        }
```

Thank you